# SQL Snowflake FILTER function - update row conditionally

Tags: sql, postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to write a query in which I update a counter based on other conditions. For example:

```
with table1 as (select *, count from table1)

select box_type, 
case when box_type = lag(box_type) over (order by time) 
then 
  count, update table1 set count = count + 1
else
  count
end as identifier
```

Here's the basic jist of what I'm trying to do. I want a table that looks like this:

```
box_type    identifier
small        1
small        1
small        1
medium       2
medium       2
large        3
large        3
small        4
```

I originally needed to do this in Postgresql. The solution was

```
select t1.*,
       count(*) filter (where box_type is distinct from prev_box_type) over (order by time) as count
from (select t1.*,
             lag(box_type) over (order by time) as prev_box_type
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
```

But I am unable to get this to work in Snowflake syntax.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
select t1.*,
       sum(case when box_type is distinct from prev_box_type then 1 else 0 end) over (order by time) as count
from (select t1.*,
             lag(box_type) over (order by time) as prev_box_type
      from table1 t1
     ) t1;
```

Or more simply as:

```
select t1.*,
       sum( (box_type is distinct from prev_box_type)::int ) over (order by time) as count
```

Or the built-in function [`conditional_change_event()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event.html):

```
select t1.*,
       conditional_change_event(box_type) over (order by time) as count
from table1 t1;
```

Comment: I'm getting an SQL Compilation Error. Saying that it is not a valid group by expression

Comment: @Brad . . . That is an odd error.  None of these are using `group by`.  All are window functions.